# How to pass one element of a clist as an int argument for another function?

Tags: pdftex, expl3, latex3

This is the minimal example for my question:

I want to convert one element of a `clist` to `int` to be able to pass them to another function. This breaks with `undefined control sequence`. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\hours}{m}
{
    \fp_eval:n { #1 / 60 } h
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{mm}
{
    \clist_clear_new:N \l__timelist_testing_clist
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l__timelist_testing_clist { #1 * 60 }
    
    \l__timelist_testing_clist \\
    \fp_eval:n {  \clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } {1} } \\
    \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_eval:n {  \clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } {1} }) } \\
    
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int
        { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_eval:n {  \clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } {1} }) } }
    
    \hours{ \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    new:
    
    \strtime{2}{h}
    
\end{document}
```

================================================================
To understand why I want to do this now the full example:

With valuable help from here I was able to create a few functions for summing up time values in different units (h, d, min) and then display that sum in a useful way.

Also I was able to calculate the median from a `clist` of time values from different units (as above) and return it.

What I was not able to make work is to use the same functionality to then display the resulting median value (in minutes) in a useful way as with the sum.

Somehow I am not able to convert the `clist` variable that is the output of the median function to an integer to make it possible to work as a valid input for the function that displays that minute value in useful ways...

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newtime}{m}
{
    \fp_new:c { g__timecalc_time_#1_fp }
    \fp_new:c { g__timecalc_factor_#1_fp} % factor to divide the result by after the table
}
\newtime{default} % initialize one

% \addtime* will also show the added time
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtime}{sO{default}mm}
{
    \timecalc_time_add:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
    
    % with \addtime* also show what's been added    
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}
}

% show the result of the sum in g__timecalc_time_#1_fp with biggest unit being #2
\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{O{default}m}
{
    \timecalc_time_str:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}

\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_days_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_hours_int
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int

% add the given time #2 with given unit #3 to __timecalc_time_#1_fp
\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_add:nnn
{
    \str_case:nnF { #3 }
    {
        {h}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g__timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 } }
        {d}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g__timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 * 60 * 24 } }
        {min}{ \fp_gadd:cn { g__timecalc_time_#1_fp } { #2 } }
    }
    {\ERROR}
}

% calculate #1 = #1 / #2 and return the modulo in #3
\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_int_div_mod:nnn {
    \int_set:Nn #3 
    { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
    
    \int_set:Nn #1
    { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
}

% round the sum in g__timecalc_time_#1_fp and show value with biggest unit being #2
\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_str:nn
{
    % round to full minutes
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
    { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:c { g__timecalc_time_#1_fp }, 0 ) } }
    
    \timecalc_time_strshow:nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int { #2 }
}

% show the value of \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int with biggest unit being #2
\cs_new_protected:Nn \timecalc_time_strshow:nn
{
    \bool_if:nTF
    {
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{d}
    }
    {%yes
        % compute and remove the number of days
        \timecalc_int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{1440}{\l__timecalc_time_days_int}
        
        % now print the days
        \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_days_int > 0 }
        { \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_days_int }\,\textup{d}\; }
        {
            \unkern
        }
    }{} % no
    
    \bool_if:nTF
    {
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{h} ||
        \str_if_eq_p:nn{#2}{d} 
    }
    {% yes
        % compute and remove the number of hours
        \timecalc_int_div_mod:nnn{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_int}{60}{\l__timecalc_time_hours_int}
        
        % now print the hours
        \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int > 0 }
        {
            \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_hours_int }\,\textup{h}\;
        }
        {% no hours
            \unkern
        }       
    }{} % no
    
    
    % now print the minutes
    \int_compare:nTF { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int > 0 }
    {
        \int_eval:n { \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int }\,\textup{min}
    }
    {% no minutes
        \unkern
    }
}

% =====================
%  time list and median calculations

% show the median of the clist in #1
\NewDocumentCommand{\listmedian}{m}
{
    \timelist_median:x { #1 }
}

\clist_new:N \l__timelist_median_clist
\int_new:N \l__timelist_median_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \timelist_median:n
{
    % set a comma separated list
    \clist_set:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { #1 }
    % sort it numerically
    \clist_sort:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist
    {
        \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > ##2 }
        { \sort_return_swapped: }
        { \sort_return_same: }
    }
    % compute the number of items
    \int_set:Nn \l__timelist_median_int { \clist_count:N \l__timelist_median_clist }
    \int_if_odd:nTF {\l__timelist_median_int }
    {% if the number is odd, return the middle item
        \clist_item:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { (\l__timelist_median_int + 1)/2 }
    }
    {% otherwise the average of the middle two elements
        \fp_eval:n
        {
            ( 
            \clist_item:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { \l__timelist_median_int/2 }
            +
            \clist_item:Nn \l__timelist_median_clist { \l__timelist_median_int/2 + 1 }
            )/2
        }
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \timelist_median:n { x }

\clist_clear_new:N \g__timelist_median_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtimelist}{sO{default}mm}
{
    \str_case:nnF { #4 }
    {
        {h}{ \clist_gput_right:Nn { \g__timelist_median_clist } { #3 * 60 } }
        {d}{ \clist_gput_right:Nn { \g__timelist_median_clist } { #3 * 60 * 24 } }
        {min}{ \clist_gput_right:Nn { \g__timelist_median_clist } { #3 } }
    }
    {
        %\ERROR
    }
    
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{#3\,\textup{#4}}    
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\timelistmedian}{O{default}}
{
    \listmedian{ \g__timelist_median_clist }
}

% should show the 
\NewDocumentCommand{\strtimelist}{O{default}m}
{
    \listmedian{ \g__timelist_median_clist }

% ========================================================
% the code from here breaks

% round to full minutes
%   \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
%   { \fp_eval:n { round( \fp_use:x { \listmedian{ \g__timelist_median_clist } }, 0 ) } } % cannot use clist as input for median?
%
%   \int_eval:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int
%\timecalc_time_strshow:nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_int { #2 }
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    addtime:
    
    \addtime*{4}{min}
    
    \addtime*{5}{h}
    
    sum = 
    
    \strtime{h}
    
    \strtime{min}
    
    \bigskip
    addtimelist:
    
    \addtimelist*{4}{min}
    
    \addtimelist*{5}{h}
    
    \timelistmedian
    
    median = \strtimelist{h}
    
\end{document}
```

I want the result of `\strtimelist{h}` to be `2 h 32 min` (152 min (median of 4 min and 5 h) converted into h and min) like with `\strtime`

Comment: One way to find errors is to reduce the functionality of the code to its minimum. Is it possible to do that here?

Comment: @projetmbc: I know it is a complicated example. However, if I remove the part for the sum I cannot give a working example for the `\strimtime` function to show it working. And when just I create a `clist` variable without much reason everybody will wonder why I did not just use `int` in the first place. I think this might be the minimal example that still shows the problem... BTW: I am not looking for any unknown problem but rather specificly wondering how the `clist` variable returned from `\timelist_median` can be used as an `int` input to other functions.

Comment: @projetmbc: I now added an MWE at the top of the question but also kept the whole example to provide sense.

Comment: a clist is a comma-list, how can you make  comma separated list of things an integer??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: maybe I have not clearly stated what I want: I want to turn just one element of the clist into an int. I am not really sure about variable types and casting in LaTeX. Is the return value of \clist_item:nn not a clist?

Comment: you are passing the whole list not an item,`\clist_put_right:Nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } { #1 * 60 }` is wrong as `N` arguments should not have `{}` but it adds the text `2*60` to a list, `\fp_eval:n { \l__timelist_testing_clist }`  passes the whole list to fpeval which might accidentally not give an error if the list only has one value.  `\clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist }` only passes one argument to `\clist_item:nn` when it requires 2. sorry I can't guess the intention of this code or suggest changes

Comment: `Is the return value of \clist_item:nn not a clist?` no, if you have  list of integers that selects one item so would be an integer not a clist

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did indead placed one `}` wrongly. Thanks for the hint. I have corrected the MWE code and updated a function to show what I am trying to do: pass one element of the clist to that function and then perform calculations with that int. If the return value of `\clist_item:nn` is indeed an int I understand even less why that breaks...

Comment: it would be an int if you had  a list of int but your list item was `2*60`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I guess you are right and that is it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int 
                                                 
l.27     \strtime{2}{h}
                       
?
```

so declare the variable

```
\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int
```

then no error reported but

```
\clist_put_right:Nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } { #1 * 60 }
```

should be

```
\clist_put_right:Nn  \l__timelist_testing_clist  { #1 * 60 }
```

then

```
    \fp_eval:n { \l__timelist_testing_clist }
```

is passing the entire list to `fpeval` which accidentally works as there is only one item, but if there are never more than one item, why use  a list?

perhaps change to

```
    \clist_put_right:Nx  \l__timelist_testing_clist  {\fp_eval:n{ #1 * 60} }
```

then you get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

as you have

```
\clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist }
```

to select an item from a list but are missing an argument to say which item

perhaps

```
\clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } {1}
```

this runs without error producing

[image]

but I have no idea if that is the intended output

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\strtime}{mm}
{
    \clist_clear_new:N \l__timelist_testing_clist
    \clist_put_right:Nx  \l__timelist_testing_clist  {\fp_eval:n{ #1 * 60} }

    
    % round to full minutes
    \int_set:Nn \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int
        { \fp_eval:n { round( \clist_item:nn { \l__timelist_testing_clist } {1} ) } }
    
    \int_eval:n{\l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int}
    
    %\strtimegen [ \l__timecalc_time_minutes_testing_int ] {#2}
    
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    new:
    
    \strtime{2}{h}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the corrections. I understand them and will remember to work more carefully next time. I slowly get the grasp of `expl3`. I guess the `\fp_eval:n{ #1 * 60}` for the elements of the list really is the solution to the whole problem. As I suspected, the meaning of my code got lost in the MWE. The real code (lower part of my question) wants to take the median element from the clist and then split it into hours and minutes and display it.